# Why do I still get an older version of Dropbox when downloading the latest one?

Tags: 11.04, dropbox

In Natty I downloaded the latest version of Dropbox from their [website](https://www.dropbox.com/install). It should come with an appindicator rather than a systray icon, and it does so on my other Maverick installation.

However, it does not for some reason. That is very inconvenient, as these icons are blocked in Natty. I suppose that for some reason the system still installed an older version of Dropbox. How can i fix that/get the latest version to install?

Comment: I think this is a dropbox bug (I have the same problem).

Comment: Jorge, you are using dropbox and not Ubuntu One :)? Shame on you ;)

Comment: Error confirmed in 17.04 as well. Solution worked for 17.04 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out myself. It's actually very simple!

First, stop Drobpox. This can be done easily by entering the following terminal command:

```
dropbox stop
```

Now download the following .zip file: http://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/17/dropbox-lnx.x86-1.0.20.tar.gz
Or: Get the latest one if it should exist by the time you read this.

The content of that .zip file should look like this, only containing the folder `.dropbox-dist`

[image: How the .zip file should look like]

Now simply extract this .zip file into your home folder. You will be prompted to merge the existing folder with your new one. Do this and confirm all requests for overwriting.

Now simply start Dropbox again, which is easily done by:

```
dropbox start
```

Enjoy!

Comment: 8 years later and this tip still saves my workday. BTW, the latest download link can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/install. FWIW, the direct link to the 64-bit tarball is currently https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64.

Answer (score 6):

I use 10.10 and this [forums on Dropbox forum](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=33943&replies=2#post-295959) helped me.

You have to manually reinstall `drobpoxd` (`dropbox stop; rm -r ~/.dropbox-dist/; dropbox start -i`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the try, but that did not help for some reason. Is there a way I can check which version of dropboxd is running?

Comment: Synaptic says that i have 0.6.7 version of nautilus-dropbox and ~/.dropbox-dist/VERSION says 1.2.0. And it shows in the indicator applet. Unfortunately I can't help you other way. Good luck.

Comment: Interesting! Just checked ~/.dropbox-dist/VERSION and it says 0.7.110. Although I ran the commands you gave me. How could that ever happen?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks! :). After removing the folder, on next start Dropbox will automatically download the latest version. Apparently the Ubuntu package is actually just a friendly installer.